# Serialization of nested Action<T> for service bus Queue

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

The general consensus from reading other posts is that serializing anonymous delegates and actions etc is a bad idea and brittle etc.  The lifetime of these serialized actions will be very short lived but i'm open to better ideas about how to accomplish what i'm doing.

I have a web role and a worker role.  The user can upload massive amounts of data that I need to split down and send to external wcf services.  I need to queue this data and I just wanted a generic interface. I'd like to be able to deserialize it and call Execute() on it without having custom logic in the worker role.

I have 4 external services (may grow) each with multiple calls and there own unique parameters.  I wanted a method of constructing the parameters in the web role, declaring which serviceInvoker class and interface I want to construct (generates a ChannelFactory with client credentials etc), and executing the child method with said parameters.

```
// Code
var queueMessage = new WorkOutMessage<IService1>(User.agent.Client.Id,
           new Action<ServiceInvoker<IService1>>(serviceInvoker =>
                   serviceInvoker.InvokeService(proxy =>
                   {
                        using (new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)proxy))
                        {
                            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.ReplyTo = new EndpointAddress("https://someAddress.com/");
                            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.MessageId = new System.Xml.UniqueId(head.CorrelationID);
                            proxy.SomeChildFunction(envelope);
                        }
                   })));

var stream = new MemoryStream();
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(stream, queueMessage;
var brokeredMessage =  new BrokeredMessage(stream) { CorrelationId = correlationId };

// Formatter.Serialize throws an exception  
Type '<MyController>+<>c__DisplayClassc' in Assembly '<MyDll>, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

// Classes
public interface IQueueProxyMessage
{
    int Attempts();
    bool Execute();
}

[Serializable]
public class WorkOutMessage<T> : IQueueProxyMessage where T : class
{
    public Guid clientId { get; set; }
    public Action<ServiceInvoker<T>> action { get; set; }
    public int attempts { get; set; }

    public WorkOutMessage(Guid clientId, Action<ServiceInvoker<T>> action) 
    {
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.action = action;
        this.attempts = 0;
    }

    public int Attempts()
    {
        return this.attempts;
    }

    public bool Execute()
    {
        this.attempts++;
        try
        {
            var config = InfrastructureConfiguration.Instance;
            var storage = new AzureStorageService();
            var db = new DbContext(config.azure.dbConnectionString,
                                            DbValidationMode.Enabled,
                                            DbLazyLoadingMode.Disabled,
                                            DbAutoDetectMode.Enabled);
            var client = db.Client.Include(x => x.Organisation)
                                .Include(x => x.Certificate)
                                .Where(x => x.Active
                                         && x.Organisation.Active
                                         && x.Certificate != null
                                         && x.Id == this.clientId)
                                .FirstOrDefault();
            if(client != null)
            {
                X509Certificate2 clientCert;
                string clientCertContentType;
                byte[] clientCertContent;
                if (storage.GetBlob(AzureBlobType.Certificate, client.Certificate.StorageId.ToString(), out clientCertContentType, out clientCertContent))
                {
                    var base64EncodedBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(clientCertContent);
                    clientCert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedBytes), "test", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
                    if(clientCert != null)
                    {
                        var serviceInvoker = new ServiceInvoker<T>(client.Id, "test", clientCert, config.publicCertificate);
                        if(serviceInvoker != null)
                        {
                            this.action.Invoke(serviceInvoker);
                        }
                        // error
                    }
                    // error
                }
                // error
            }
            else
            {

            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Obviously my serialization knowledge is pretty non-existant. which is why I thought this would work in the first place. Is there any way to re-architect this so I can still specify what serviceInvoker to use, what method and pass the parameters?

Edit: the code where I try to use BinaryFormatter and Exception

Edit2: This is a bad idea, i'm going to pass the data and reconstruct the class on the worker.

Comment: Does this work or not? What kind of exceptions are thrown?

Comment: Added the exception, I assume this is due to it instantiating the Action? or me maybe passing a variable off the stack?

Comment: The Exception is clear: that class that gets serialized has no `Serializable` attribute and by the looks of it as it is an anonymous type it will never get one. You might try to use the DataContractSerializer instead but I don't expect that the classes you try to serialize will play nicely.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to serialize live objects. Try serializing the parameters, then recreating the live objects on the worker. Have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yeah after some discussion I think this is a terrible idea.  I'm going to pass the data and reconstruct the class on the worker.